# IIS Web Farm AppPool warm-up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5

I have multiple servers (2012 R2 with IIS 8.5) that have shared configuration, shared vanity URL (f5 load balanced), and host several different applications.  One of the applications (an ASP.NET MVC web app) is rarely used (maybe once or twice a week) but when it needs to be used, it needs to load quickly.

I've set the AppPool to have a Start Mode of "AlwaysRunning", and a Recycling -> Regular Time Interval to 0, but it seems like every time I hit the app, it takes forever to load (like 10-20 seconds) but subsequent page requests happen instantly.

Is there another setting that I need to set to keep the app warmed up?  The app has Kerberos Authentication and access is limited to one security group (that I'm not even a member of), so I can't use external PowerShell scripts to manually keep it warm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if the application pool is running before you hit the app.

If you click on your server name in IIS then click on "Worker Processes" you'll see all the Process ID's of the different application pools and that state.

This way you can confirm the app pool is running, before you access the application.  This will help you narrow down where the problem exists.

1) Is the app pool running? 
2) Is my app loaded in my app pool?

If 1 checks out, then move on to step 2 and check to see if the libraries of that application is loaded up in that Process ID.

Answer (score 1):

Check your event log for application pool failures.

If you have some asynchronous initialisation/maintenance task which is started in parallel with the request or with some delay and subsequently fails, it can make the request (and some afterward) succeed but kill the application pool shortly after. This would exhibit these exact symptoms.